# Get number from EditText to TextView and add

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

I want when i write 5 in the EditText then i click the button i want the TextView to change to 5, then if i write 6 and click again on the button i want the TextView to change to 11...

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="how much do you want to add ?"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:id="@+id/TextView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:onClick="add"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:hint="add"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. 
But it is also equally important that you search first and do some research before posting your question. 
Also include what you have tried and indicate the problem(s) you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following code snippet. Make sure to add conditions/check that input is always in numeric:

```
yourbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(yourtxtview.getText().toString().trim().length()>0 ){
                if(youredtText.getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
                    yourtxtview.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(yourtxtview.getText().toString())
                            +Integer.valueOf(youredtText.getText().toString())));
                }else{
                    yourtxtview.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(yourtxtview.getText().toString())+
                            0));

                }
            }else if(youredtText.getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
                yourtxtview.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(youredtText.getText().toString())+
                        0));
            }
        }
    });
```